Error Call to a member function on null
I've created custom module for event and observer to restrict some city from COD.
However I'm facing an error at checkout page and inside the log I found the following error:
Error(code: 0): Call to a member function getShippingAddress() on null

Observer :
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class PaymentMethodAvailable implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_appState;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\State $appState
    ) {
        $this->_appState = $appState;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
        $method_instance = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();
        $Shipping =$observer->getEvent()->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();

        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
          /* 
          *  During Checkout magento call payment methods from both
          *   area frontend and Web_api are
          */

            if($method_instance->getCode() == 'cashondelivery')
            {

            if( strtolower($Shipping['city']) == 'liverpool'){
                    $result->setData('is_available',true); 
                }
                else{

                    $result->setData('is_available',false); 
                }
            }
        
    }      
}


The error message Error(code: 0): Call to a member function getShippingAddress() on null indicates that $observer->getEvent()->getQuote() is returning null. To resolve this issue, check if the quote is falsy and return early if it is.
Detailed implementation:
Replace the following code:
$result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
$method_instance = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();
$Shipping =$observer->getEvent()->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();

with
$quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
if (!$quote) {
    return;
}

$result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
$method_instance = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();
$Shipping = $quote->getShippingAddress();

Additionally, I noticed that the $_appState property is not being used and identified several areas where the code could be improved. I have optimized it accordingly. Below is the updated code for your class:
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address;
use Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Cashondelivery;
use Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;

class PaymentMethodAvailable implements ObserverInterface
{
    // Define restricted cities as lowercase to simplify comparison
    private const RESTRICTED_CITIES = ['liverpool'];

    /**
     * @param EventObserver $observer
     */
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer): void
    {
        // Retrieve the quote from the observer
        /** @var CartInterface $quote */
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();

        // If quote is falsy, exit early
        if (!$quote) {
            return;
        }

        // Retrieve payment method instance
        $methodInstance = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();

        // Check for cash on delivery method
        /** @var AbstractMethod $methodInstance */
        if ($methodInstance->getCode() === Cashondelivery::PAYMENT_METHOD_CASHONDELIVERY_CODE) {
            /** @var Address $shippingAddress */
            // Retrieve shipping address
            $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
            $city = strtolower($shippingAddress->getCity());

            // Check if the city is in the restricted list
            if (in_array($city, self::RESTRICTED_CITIES)) {
                $result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
                $result->setData('is_available', false);
            }
        }
    }
}



Hi @tu-van thank you soooo much it's working now.
One last question, is it possible to add cities name in Arabic inside the array ?

Hey @Dun7ill I don't have sample data to verify this, but I believe you can confirm it easily.
